# How to find the average rating for a movie

Tags: pandas

considering the following data frames and columns:
movies_df = ['userId', 'movieId', 'rating', 'timestamp']
rating_df = ['movieId', 'title', 'genres']

Answer (score 0):

Assuming 'rating' is a number, [pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.mean](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.mean.html) should work:

```
movies_df.groupby('movieId')['rating'].mean()
```

EDIT BASED ON COMMENT:

It seems that you need to groupby and average the ratings from the first df and then merge those results in the second df. Something like:

```
avg_ratings = movies_df.groupby('movieId')['rating'].mean().reset_index()
merged = pd.merge(rating_df, avg_ratings, how='outer')
```

`merged`will contain the info with movieId, title, genre, and 'avg_rating'

Comment: I explicitly refered to two dataframes (aka two tables linked by the movieID column) Each the answer should be a table with [title(name of movie)] and [mean rating] - by way of linking the tables.  Sorry if wasn't clear

Comment: Oh, that was not entirely clear to me, please check if the edited answer is helpful.